# Search queries not returning on inputs

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a search form to make finding products easier. unfortunately it isn't querying from my input and is just returning all the fields...

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    //
    $types = Category::all();
    $products = Product::where('approved', '=', 1)->leftJoin('reviews', 'reviews.product_id', '=', 'product.id')->select('product.*', DB::raw('AVG(ratings) as ratings_average' ))->groupBy('id')->orderBy('ratings_average', 'DESC')->get();



    $name=$request->input('name');
    $type=$request->input('categories_id');


    if(!empty($name)){
        $products->Where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%');
    }
    if(!empty($type)){
        $products->Where('categories_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$type.'%');
    }


    return view('pages.search')->withProducts($products)->withTypes($types)
```

View:

```
                {!! Form::open(['route' => 'search.index', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}

                    {!! Form::label('name', 'Search By Name:') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                </div>



                    {!! Form::label('categories_id', 'Search By Category:') !!}
                    <select class="form-control" name="categories_id" >
                        <option value=""></option>

                        @foreach($types as $type)

                            <option value="{{$type->id}}">{{$type->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>

                </div>

                    {!! Form::submit('Find Product', array('class' => ' btn-lg btn-block')) !!}
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Controller:

```
Route::get('search', 'SearchController@index')->name('search.index');
```

Any ideas why nothing seems to be happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$products->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%');` instead. (`where` all lowercase)

But the better way would be to add the search criteria while querying the database itself rather than getting all the results and then applying the criteria on the result collection.

```
$productsQuery = Product::where('approved', '=', 1)
->leftJoin('reviews', 'reviews.product_id', '=', 'product.id')
->select('product.*', DB::raw('AVG(ratings) as ratings_average' ));

 $name=$request->input('name');
    $type=$request->input('categories_id');


    if($request->has('name')){
        $productsQuery->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->input('name').'%');
    }
    if($request->has('categories_id')){
        $productsQuery->where('categories_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->input('categories_id').'%');
    }

$products = $productsQuery->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use your where conditions before making ->get().
When you are calling get() methods it queries to db. Otherwise you can use collections filters(not recommended in this case).